# Definining a constant that holds all OR-ed values

Tags: c

My application make use of *OR-ed* values, like this example (pseudo):

```
#define OPTION_1      1
#define OPTION_2      2
#define OPTION_3      4
#define OPTION_4      8
```

These constants gets *OR-ed* in various functions in the form of integers, like that:

```
OPTION_1 | OPTION_4 ...
```

Sometimes i have many *OPTIONS* to pass on a function that i rather not. I prefer to have a option constant like that:

```
#define OPTION_ALL      ??   <-- include all options
```

to hold anything and instead pass that as a default maybe.

Is this possible? I tried:

```
#define OPTION_ALL      8
```

Or is this the only solution?

```
#define OPTION_ALL      OPTION_1 | OPTION_2 | OPTION_3 | OPTION_4
```

**SOLUTION:**

It seems this is the best way:

```
#define OPTION_1      0
#define OPTION_2      1
#define OPTION_3      2
#define OPTION_4      4
#define OPTION_ALL    (OPTION_4 * 2) - 1
```

It just uses the last option as input

Comment: `OPTION_ALL` should be 7, not 8. And this is also why you *should* write the OR explicitly, it protects you from your own math errors.

Comment: `#define OPTION_ALL 0xffffffff` will not only include current options, but options which would be defined in future as it has all bits set. BTW, why do you define `OPTION_1` as zero?

Comment: @StoryTeller, yes i tested them, goes like 1,3,5,7 depending on how many values i OR about. However this requires a hard coded value anytime i update my options :(

Comment: Well, you can do what **myaut** suggested, just make sure you also define an unsigned type to hold all those options.

Comment: @myaut, no reason at all. I thought it's ok as long as i double the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, But `OPTION_1` cannot be 0. It should be 1 and then `OPTION_ALL` will be 15

```
#define OPTION_1      1
#define OPTION_2      2
#define OPTION_3      4
#define OPTION_4      8
#define OPTION_ALL    15
```

Basically what you are doing is that you are setting one bit in binary as 1 for each option. i.e.

```
#define OPTION_1      0b00000001
#define OPTION_2      0b00000010
#define OPTION_3      0b00000100
#define OPTION_4      0b00001000
#define OPTION_ALL    0b00001111
```

And you can then extend as necessary.

Comment: Should be noted that binary constants are an extension, and not standard C

Comment: replace 0b with 0x numbers to make it portable.

Comment: I used binary for better understanding, Once that is there, the decimal or hex numbers can be used.

Comment: I see thanx. So i just have to subtract 1 from the next value for `OPTION_ALL`, assuming im starting from `1`?. `OPTION_5    16` and `OPTION_ALL 31` are valid?